# Set the JSONArray Data into the AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, json, autocompletetextview

i am trying to set my autocompleteTextview with jsondata...here is my code

```
JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, strUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {


                 @Override
                 public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                     JSONArray ja;

                     State1 = new ArrayList<>();
                     try {

                         String istate = null;
                         ja = response;
                         for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                             istate = ja.getJSONObject(i).getString("Name").trim();

                             State1.add(istate);

                             ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,State1);
                             adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                             state.setAdapter(adapter);

                         }

                     } catch (Exception e) {
                         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                     }

                 }
             }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                 }
             });
```

the json i want to parse is...

[
   {
      "Name":"Andaman and Nicobar Islands",
      "Code":1157
   },
   {
      "Name":"Andhra Pradesh",
      "Code":1158
   },
   {
      "Name":"Arunachal Pradesh",
      "Code":1159
   }

]

my problem is the data does not get set into the autocompletetextview...what m i doing wrong?

Comment: why `JSONArray ` ???

Comment: what should i use then?...

Comment: At first make sure `JSONArray response` having value

Comment: i am getting the response to work...but i am not getting how to set this values to arraylist so that i can set it autocompletetextview

Comment: Does state refers to AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: yes i initiliased state to autoCompleteView